# Does it make sense to use conda as a gernal purpose package manager?

Tags: conda

I'm trying to decide if I could/should leverage [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/) (which is a python environment/package manager) to manage packages that have nothing to do with python. In the conda docs it is mentioned that conda is a python agnostic binary package manager, which indicates to me that it should be possible. The question is, is it sensible?

My use-case does not require any fancy integration, just simply extracting the 'packages' at the correct destination is sufficient. What I like about conda is the dependency resolution, and package update capabilities.

PS: I'm not quite sure if stackoverflow is the ideal platform for this question, but I figured that the most people familiar with conda can be found here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it makes sense. This is what I do. I have a lot of packages built at binstar.org/asmeurer that are not Python packages, like `emacs`, `gcc`, `fortune`, just as some random examples. Conda was designed to work with any kind of package.

You probably shouldn't use it to manage packages that have to be installed at the system level (like your Linux kernel).

You may end up having to build conda packages for stuff if you find it isn't built yet, but that's [easy enough](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build.html), and you can often find a package already on Binstar.